# IIS7.5 non-http port routing

Tags: routing, iis-7.5, telnet, vnc

I am trying to use IIS7.5 as a way to route to vnc on different servers or virtual servers. I cant get http to work but not non-http protocols like VNC, telnet, etc. Is there a way to do that?

example:

```
site1.webaddress.com:5902 --> 192.168.1.100:5902
site2.webaddress.com:23   --> 192.168.1.101:23
```

UPDATE:

Windows Home Server 2008 (Windows 2008). I realize that IIS is a poor solution but I am trying not to add too much complexity.

I don't have a TCP proxy or a hardware firewall. I have a simple router that can do port forwarding but does not understand DNS. I create virtual servers so I'd like to be able to get at them via domain name or even better subdomain name.

What would be preferable would be www.domain.com/server_name/function.

Trying to be simple but it seems like maybe that is not possible.

P.S. I got the idea because of the RDP capability within WHS 2011.

Comment: IIS is an HTTP server, so its purpose in life is to serve HTTP content. Using WAS, you can host non-HTTP WCF services. It MAY be possible to use this to host a non-HTTP proxy (though I even doubt this, as that is probably designed to support short request-response sessions, not a continuously open, bidirectional TCP connection), however, IIS is a terrible solution to this problem. Is your requirement to specifically use IIS, or are you open to other tools (such as a firewall or generic TCP proxy) to solve it? If so, what is your environment? What firewall? Windows verison?

Comment: I'm open to any solution that can help with this and co-exist with IIS.